# How is bulb affecting power feeding light fixture?

Tags: electrical

I have a very simple light fixture that [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNxe7.png) and a [simple tester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fifbE.png). The issue here is that I've installed several regular light bulbs, and it's always very inconsistent.

On Saturday, I decide to check the cabling going into the fixture. I removed the light-bulb and began testing, with one lead touching the black wire and the other lead  touching the white wire. As you can see from the picture, [the tester bulb is very bright](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fFfF.png), which is how it's supposed to be.

I then installed the light-bulb and repeated the test. This time [the tester bulb is off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCWDS.png), so obviously the light-bulb won't light either. I removed the light-bulb and that was the last time I messed with that on Saturday.

On Sunday morning, I decided to see if it worked. I installed the lightbulb and turned on the switch. Lo and behold, the lightbulb's working. It worked for several hours. But then in the afternoon it stopped working and I went back to step 1.

Two questions:

1. How can the lightbulb literally "cancel" all the current that's coming from the black/white connection?
2. Why would this inexplicably work the next day? It seemed that something cooled off from Saturday to Sunday, which is why it started working on Sunday until the afternoon.

Comment: In steps 1 and 2, where is the other test lead?

Comment: The other lead isn’t touching anything

Comment: That looks like a neon light tester are their a pair of electrodes and the glow is orange/red?

Comment: is the regular light bulb lit?

Comment: A **cable** has multiple **wires** grouped together e.g. wrapped in a sheath.  A voltage tester measures presence of **voltage** (the pressure of electricity *trying* to go somewhere) not *current* (the flow of electricity actually moving).  Since current travels in loops, if the loop is not complete, the current does not travel.

Comment: Rbhat you can get a similar effect with a fluorescent lamp under a power line hold the lamp up and the field that we call the effects of phantom voltage will light the lamp , it’s not bright but somewhat similar to your neon lamp. To see the fluorescent lamp glow you have to do it at night. I have done this as a kid in school with both 4’ and 8’ tubes after an electronics instructor told us about it, I think just about every one tried it and even lamps that were black at the ends and would not light glowed their electrodes had been eaten away but the gas in the tube was still good so it worked

Comment: Whoever down-voted, care to explain why?

Comment: I have concerns about the general workmanship, given what I am seeing in the pix. It could be a problem back at the switch or any of the wiring done similarly. It looks like a DC electronics person is improvising bared on common EE splicing. A refresher on proper mains wiring splices may do the trick.

Comment: I got hit also. As I saw this it was a test to check out the voltage indicator with a question to why it’s doing what it is doing. It still looks to be a voltage drop issue as I said in my answer it could be from poor connections without an actual volt meter we will not know but a Ne2 lamp takes approximately 90 volts to strike it’s not hard to see the possibility of a large drop with those connections to get a little more scientific even a very cheap volt ohm meter (under 20$ on line with some as cheap as 10$) can be purchased that could verify this conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the tester on my desktop computer I could see that is a neon light tester. The reason the lamp is not lighting up with the light bulb in and power on is a neon light takes  90-92 volts to ignite, the lightbulb may cause enough of a voltage drop so it won’t light. I can’t really remember what the threshold is but there is normally a resistor to limit the current and that may increase the voltage needed to light but the resistor prevents the lamp from burning up once it lights.

Comment: That's not the way I'd bet.  I suspect pilot error, or possibly, voltage drop across those janky "doesn't even qualify to be called a splice" ties of wire.  I certainly hope OP skills up and does those properly.

Comment: The fact that a neon light requires ~90v  plus the resistor may shift that.  A voltage drop is what I said in my answer be it poor connections or not that is the reason it is not lighting with the lamp in place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me edit the question so that it's clearer.

Answer (score 2):

That tester is designed only to be used with both test leads on wires.  All your measurements taken with one lead floating in air, are improper use of the device, which means **the measurements are meaningless** from any practical point of view. The glow you see is a curious artifact; if you have any interest in why, that would be an appropriate question on the physics stack, not here.  Here, we'll armwave it as "phantom voltage".

As for the 2 measurements you did make with both leads in contact:

- The first measurement is correct.  Strong glow reflecting 120V between the *switched-hot* wire and the neutral wire.
- The second measurement is a user error.  The leads are not making good contact with those temporary splices you gobbed together there.  You should have gotten the same result as the first measurement.

It's also likely that the temporary splices *themselves* are failing, with poor conductivity causing heat in the splice, or even arc-faulting (though I would expect you to see arcs; rest assured they're coming if the poor connection is allowed to continue.

Do proper splices with wire nuts; for wires that size I would use orange or yellow nuts, Ideal brand to avoid handicapping yourself with cheap/flaky nuts, and torque them good-n-tight, and give each wire a firm pull-test (holding the nut) to assure it cannot pull out on its own.  Proper splicing is one of the many things you will learn as you skill up in this trade.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me edit the question so that it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was a faulty (badly corroded) light switch.

Comment: Glad you were able to lick it...what was wrong with the lightswitch, by the way?

Comment: When I removed the plastic plate, I noticed that the switch was full of rust.